# Is there a correct list of job classes for Final Fantasy Tactics: The War of the Lions on iOS?

Tags: ios, final-fantasy-tactics

The lists for Final Fantasy Tactics I've found online are wrong or, at least, appear to be. I don't know if they changed the way some of the later classes are unlocked since the PSP version, but I've been trying to unlock Samurai and both prerequisite classes and their level haven't worked (I have both Knight and Monk at level 8).

Could anyone let me know how to unlock the Samurai class or even better, give me a list of all classes and prerequisite levels to unlock them that actually works on the iOS version?

Comment: Wow, FFT, blast from the past.  Samurai also requires Dragoon to be Level 2.  I would check out (http://www.gamefaqs.com/iphone/638808-final-fantasy-tactics-the-war-of-the-lions/faqs/50312) I have a feeling this is correct, but I can't personally confirm it, so I'm leaving this as a comment instead of answer.

Comment: Ah yes, it all makes sense now. You need knight level 4, monk level 6 and  dragoon level 2. Thanks. I've checked the diagram and it all makes sense.

Comment: In that case I'm gonna post it as an answer.  Feel free to ignore it if someone posts something better :)

Comment: You also need samurai level 8 to unlock the dark knight job

Answer (score 1):

#### Base classes (no requirement)

- [Chemist](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Chemist_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29)
- [Squire](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Squire)

#### Chemist track

- [Black Mage](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Mage_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Chemist 2
- [Time Mage](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Mage_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Black Mage 3
- [Summoner](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Summoner_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Time Mage 3

- [White Mage](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/White_Mage_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Chemist 2
- [Mystic](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Mystic) — White Mage 3
- [Orator](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Orator) — Mystic 3

- [Arithmetician](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Arithmetician) — Black Mage 5, Mystic 4, Time Mage 4, White Mage 5
- [Bard](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Bard_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Orator 5, Summoner 5, Male charater

#### Squire track

- [Archer](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Archer_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Squire 2
- [Thief](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Thief_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Archer 3
- [Dragoon](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Dragoon_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Thief 4

- [Knight](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Knight_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Squire 2
- [Monk](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Monk_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Knight 3
- [Geomancer](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Geomancer_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Monk 4

- [Ninja](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Ninja_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Archer 4, Geomancer 2, Thief 5
- [Samurai](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Samurai_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Dragoon 2, Knight 4, Monk 5
- [Dancer](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Dancer_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Dragoon 5, Geomancer 5, Female character

#### Hybrid track

- [Dark Knight](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Knight_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Black Mage ★, Dragoon 8, Geomancer 8, Knight ★, Ninja 8, 20 kills<sup>1</sup>
- [Mime](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Mime_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Chemist 8, Dragoon 5, Geomancer 5, Orator 5, Squire 8, Summoner 5
- [Onion Knight](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Onion_Knight_%28Final_Fantasy_Tactics%29) — Chemist 6, Squire 6

<sup>Note 1: character must turn into a crystal to count as a kill.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I saved this picture to my phone, its really useful and quick this way.

[image: I saved this picture to my phone its really useful and quick]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be pretty accurate: [FFT War of the Lions class level requirements chart](http://www.gamefaqs.com/iphone/638808-final-fantasy-tactics-the-war-of-the-lions/faqs/50312)

For Samurai specifically, it seems you need Dragoon to be Level 2 as well.