# Are the class requirements different in Final Fantasy Tactics for the iPhone?

Tags: ios, final-fantasy-tactics

I bought the iPhone version of Final Fantasy Tactics, and I just levelled my Thief to 3 and my Monk to 3. It was my understanding that at this point the Thief could upgrade to a Lancer and the Monk could become a Geomancer.  I looked up the level requirements and I was right. Yet, when I go to change their classes, the option for Lancer or Geomancer do not show up.

Are the level requirements different for the iPhone?  Is there something I may be missing?

Comment: You may also want to review [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47857/correct-list-of-job-classes-for-fftwotl-ios) and its answers.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently yes. I just opened it on my phone and Geomancer's only requirement is Monk 4. Similarly, Dragoon's is Thief 4.

Comment: You know what the differences are for ninja? I just got Monk lv5 and Archer lv5 on one character.... still no option for Ninja.

Comment: @REDace0 The Ninja class requires a lv4 Thief, lv5 Archer, and lv2 Geomancer.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your title question is **yes**.

The game originally released for the PlayStation 1 ([Final Fantasy Tactics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_Tactics)) is indeed different from the one you purchased on your iPhone ([Final Fantasy Tactics: The War of the Lions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_Tactics:_The_War_of_the_Lions)).

To quote directly from Wikipedia's section on **Versions and re-releases**:

> A PlayStation Portable version of Final Fantasy Tactics, entitled
> Final Fantasy Tactics: The War of the Lions was released on May 10,
> 2007, in Japan; and is now released across all regions. It is the
> second game announced as part of the Ivalice Alliance. The game
> features an updated version of Final Fantasy Tactics, along with new
> features including in-game cutscenes, new characters, and multiplayer
> capability. **The updated mechanics contain a 16:9 widescreen support,
> new items, new jobs, and cel-shaded full motion videos.** The English
> version contains full voice acting during the cinematic cut scenes,
> whereas the Japanese version does not.
>
> War of the Lions was ported to
> iOS in 2011, with the iPhone version released on August 4, 2011, and
> an iPad version was released February 2012.

*emphasis added*

There are many websites offering job trees, but I found that this one was particularly well-suited for my iPhone screen: [FFT Job Tree](http://squarehaven.com/games/PS-Portable/Final-Fantasy-Tactics-War-of-the-Lions/guide/jobs/)